# Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.4.4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to run a  spring mvc and hibernate project, I am getting the following error:

> Failed to execute goal on project spring-mvc-tiles-hibernate: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sprin.mvc:spring-mvc-tiles-hibernate:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.4.4 in http://192.168.200.35:8080/artifactory/libs-release was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sprin.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-mvc-tiles-hibernate</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-mvc-tiles-hibernate</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
        <finalName>spring-mvc-tiles-hibernate</finalName>
        <!-- <plugins> <plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.4</version> 
            <configuration> In version 2.1-alpha-1, this was incorrectly named warSourceExcludes 
            <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes> <archive> <manifest> 
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> <classpathPrefix>C:/Users/hunaid.husain/workspace/rest-web-app/target/rest-web-app/WEB-INF/lib/</classpathPrefix> 
            </manifest> </archive> </configuration> </plugin> </plugins> -->
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <servlet-api.version>2.5.0</servlet-api.version>
        <dwr.version>3.0.0-rc3-SNAPSHOT</dwr.version>
        <tiles-version>2.2.2</tiles-version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <jackson.version>2.0.4</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>${tiles-version}</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
                 <!-- Json via Jackson 2.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
      <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>${dwr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
     <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
     <version>1.1</version>
     </dependency> 


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What did you try do far? What did google give you on this?

Comment: @Aditi Please delete the cached copy of that jar from your local repository. You can attach the pom file with your question.

Comment: Oracle doesn't put their drivers in maven central, so you'll have to provide these in your own nexus or locally or in your own libs.

Comment: I changed different versions of ojdbc jar and tried executing it through maven install, but it did'nt work. I also changed the version of the commons-dbcp to 1.4 due to which the error for it resolved. Can you kindly suggest what else can I do?

Comment: Posterity, A concise article on the topic @ https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/

Answer (score 2):

I was in simmilar situation recently.
Oracle does not provide driver package physically to maven, but maven has  driver artifacts in its repository. So, when you set up  dependency inside the pom.xml , you actually dowloading  oracle license file  only.

Solution for me was next :

1. Pom dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
   <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Build the project, it will except that it cannot download jar , but will create  folders in local repository.

In my case under Windows :

```
  C:\Users\Daniel\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc\10.2.0.4.0\
```

This folder will have some files inside but no jar.

3. Download driver manually from Oracle site ( ver 10.2.0.4.0) :
   [Oracle JDBC drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html)
4. Instal driver  into maven manually by running

   ```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path/to/your/ojdbc.jar} -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc -Dversion=10.2.0.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
   ```

Where **com.oracle** and **ojdbc**  in command  has to match  with  maven repo path elements ...\.m2\repository\**com**\**oracle**\**ojdbc**\10.2.0.4.0\

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested, but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: make sure it is ojdbc14.jar for 10.2.0.4.   Also, you can try using the higher version of the driver as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to review your dependencies, because the error show a differente version than you have in your pom.xml. You havve this in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
   <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The error show the version `10.4.4`, maybe you have another project as dependency and it has ojdbc 10.4.4.

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.

Comment: I have put proper version in the dependencies ie 10.2.0.2.0 and added the same version jar. But, the error did not go.

Answer (score 0):

Click right on your project in your IDE, find where you can setup build path/libraries and you must add the .jar file manually in project properties.

btw. You are using very old spring and junit.

[image]

Comment: I have manually added the jars, but still the error is not getting resolved. The version of spring and junit is used due to requirements of the project.